# Are there worms/snake traveling by rolling? (see youtube video)

Tags: animal-models, behaviour

Someone obtained this from a nature simulator :  https://youtu.be/l-qOBi2tAnI

Is there any animals travelling like this?

Comment: There is a [spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_spider) that rolls but I am not sure if that counts.

Comment: yes I have already seen those sand spider, but it's far less impressive...